# What does the following bash command do?

Tags: bash, command-line, command

I was just wondering what the following does when entered in bash command line (where ttyAMA0 is assumed to be a external device):

```
#define SER_PORT "/dev/ttyAMA0"
```

Comment: That's not a bash command, it looks like a C preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't do anything. `#` is the comment prefix in `bash`, so the whole line is a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Interesting... The following link ( http://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-55295/l/element14-how-to-use-enocean-pi-with-raspberry-pi ) says to input this line. I guess then it should be a C/C++ line... Thanks again!!

Comment: Yes. The previous step said to download the EnOcean Link code, and this is something you're supposed to change in one of its files.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, that makes sense now. I think it is a badly written tutorial for noobs such as I.